# Microsoft Azure setup Server firewall?

Tags: azure

I have a free account on Azure through Microsoft Imagine and I make sample windows app; just send name to a database and it works correctly, but the problem is when I set the server firewall and add my IP if my IP changed, my app doesn't work till adding my new IP.

Is there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: Please read the help section on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking  As it stands, this question will get flagged and deleted for being low quality.

Comment: As Gram mentioned, this question does not really belong here. Try asking this same thing on MSDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either open up azure to allow **ALL** IP addresses or pay for an ISP that offers a static IP address.

If you opened up the firewall, then I suggest you add to what your sending a password or something so that the server knows it's you. If it's really important, then also think about encryption of that message.